# How to rename the dummy file if actual file is not available

Tags: bash, unix, awk, putty

In a directory 4 dummy files are present.

1. acc_bal.1.txt
2. acc_dir.1.txt
3. acc_liq.1.txt
4. acc_trans.1.txt

Using some other process i am getting some files in same directory.

**For exapmple:**
under this directory following files are coming--
      *acc_bal_1_20022017_1.txt*
    *acc_dir_1_20022017_1.txt*
.  #[*20022017- current date ddmmyyyy]

Since ***acc_liq_1_20022017_1.txt***  and  ***acc_trans_1_20022017.txt*** files are missing,
but we need all 4 files according to requirement.

So consider the dummy files **acc_liq.1.txt** , **acc_trans.1.txt** and rename it to

*acc_liq_1_20022017_1.txt

 acc_trans_1_20022017_1.txt*

I need to write unix script in putty for above situation.

I started with below script
`for mypattern in ls -1 DIR | cut -d'_' -f3-4 | uniq | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'`

But i am not getting any idea to proceed further as i am beginner for unix.
Please provide the right solution.

Comment: you need to add **date** after each `1` right?

Comment: yes.. dummy files contains **.1.txt ** and we need to change it to **_1_20022017_1.txt** if it is not available for acc_liq or acc_trans or acc_bal or acc_dir

Comment: i think script needs loop which check for the presence of required file (eg : acc_bal_1_20022017_1.txt). If it is not available then rename the specific dummy file to get the unavailable required file

Answer (score 0):

I feel there are probably some other gotchas somewhere, but the following should get you started:

```
d=$(date +"_1_%d%m%Y_")

for f in *.1.txt
do
    nf=${f/./$d}

    [[ -f "$nf" ]] || mv "$f" "$nf"
done
```

This initially assumes you are in the directory of the dummy files and all other correct files don't end in '.1.txt'

Comment: Thank you for your response.  here i dont want to rename all dummy files . if correct file is not present then only rename the correspondent dummy file

Comment: Which is what the -f part will do, if the file with the dummy name and the inserted date exists it will skip and go to the next file

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got answer which is given below.

```
for myfile in `ls -1 DIR | cut -d'_' -f3-5 | sort | uniq | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'`
do
  if [ ! -f "acc_bal_$myfile" ]
    then
    cp acc_bal.1.txt acc_bal_"$myfile"
  fi
  if [ ! -f "acc_dir_$myfile" ]
    then
    cp acc_dir.1.txt acc_dir_"$myfile"
  fi
  if [ ! -f "acc_liq_$myfile" ]
    then
    cp acc_liq.1.txt acc_liq_"$myfile"
  fi
  if [ ! -f "acc_trans_$myfile" ]
    then
    cp acc_trans.1.txt acc_trans_"$myfile"
  fi
done
```

Any changes are welcome.